# How much potential energy is in a tritium glowstick?

Tags: visible-light, potential-energy, radiation

I have a small tritium key chain light I got for my birthday. It will glow for decades, so I thought it would be fun to try to figure out how bright it is in lumens, and how much energy is stored in it. I have looked on google, but there is just nothing I can find on this subject. My first approach was to treat it like an led and work backwards from luminosity to power, but I had a difficult time accurately determining its luminosity. The vial is 3mm x 22.5mm, but it's hard to tell how thick the glass is. I also don't know how efficiently the phosphor coating is in capturing the radiation and emitting visible light. Is there an accurate way to calculate these figures?

[image: A glowing tritium vial]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritium_radioluminescence

Comment: With a bit of "Googling" you can find the "decay energy" (i.e., the energy released by the decay of) a single tritium atom. If you could confidently estimate of the number of Tritium atoms in the fill gas, then answering "how much energy" would be trivial. Here's the web site of one company that makes vials like that: https://www.trigalight.com/ They might have some information that could help you. But, of course, they might not be the same company that made your vial.